# how to set https proxy for selenium's webdriver?

Tags: selenium, proxy, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

I am trying to use protractor for automated javascript testing. This means following these instructions:
http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/practical-protractor.html

```
npm install -g protractor
```

completes fine. However:

```
webdriver-manager update
```

does not get round the proxy I have at work. Apparently, you can now set the proxy in a configuration, but I can not follow how to do this: https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/966
Basically, I need to set 'env.HTTPS_PROXY', but I can't see where to do this? I can see that I could probably edit the webdriver-manager file to fix this, but that seems wrong.

Note: I have tried installing this files (from webdriver-manager update) manually and copying them into the expected locations, but the jar file becomes corrupt.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've just discovered that it is now configured to support `--proxy="<proxy>"` as an argument, so problem solved.

I also needed to use `--ignore_ssl` for this

Comment: this worked for me.  Just to clarify, "<proxy>" should be the fully qualified name for the proxy, e.g., "http://myproxyserver.domain.com:port".  Note the "http".

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific and show the full command used? Also does this support authentication?

Comment: i'm not sure on the authentication. If you mean app auth, then you could use selenium to enter the details and log into the app before running tests

Comment: Didn't work in my case. The @Cassian 's answer fixed the issue. Perhaps this is due to curl that failed to connect to update server when running update. curl knows to take proxy settings from env vars http_proxy/https_proxy.

Answer (score 17):

In cmd

```
set PROXY=http://username:password@proxyserver:port
set HTTP_PROXY=%PROXY%
set HTTPS_PROXY=%PROXY% 
webdriver-manager update
```

Or go to file .npmrc usually is here C:\Users\username.npmrc ( if not, search it with command `npm config ls -l | grep config`) and set the proxy variables manually by typing in it

```
proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver:port
https-proxy=http://username:password@proxyserver:port
```

A third way is to make two system environment variables HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY with value `http://username:password@proxyserver:port`

Comment: Setting proxy in .npmrc didn't work for me (however regularly npm can access network using proxy specified there). Setting PROXY/HTTP_PROXY/HTTPS_PROXY either in cmd or in env variables worked great (Windows 7)!

Answer (score 0):

```
webdriver-manager update
```

For me, it worked when I switched network, from proxy to without proxy and downloaded folders from the displayed URL and pasted in specified location

`\testApp>webdriver-manager update
[16:20:02] I/update - chromedriver: file exists C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.41.zip
[16:20:02] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.41.zip
[16:20:02] I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_2.41.exe up to date
[16:20:03] I/update - selenium standalone: file exists C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar
[16:20:03] I/update - selenium standalone: selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar up to date
[16:20:08] I/downloader - curl -oC:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium/geckodriver-v0.21.0.zip https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.21.0/geckodriver-v0.21.0-win64.zip`